# Access @PathVariables from parent's @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I'm trying to access the @PathVariables defined in "MyClass"'s @RequestMapping parent.
Simplified screnario:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "some/path/{with}/{multiple}/{variables}")
public class ParentClass {...}
```

This class is sort of a product's base class and should not be edited. Therefore I'm extending 'ParentClass'. In 'MyClass' I want to do something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{another}")
public Object get(@PathVariable("another") String another) {...}
```

I think this is allowed (didn't test yet), but I don't see how I would get all PathVariables that are already defined with 'ParentClass'.

Any idea/ RTFM reference on that is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/a/{a}/b/{b}")
class Parent{
}

@RestController
class Child extends Parent{
 
 // take over pathvariables from parent
 @GetMapping("/c/{c}")
 public String abc(@PathVariable String a,@PathVariable String b, @PathVariable String c) {
        return a+b+c;
 }
 
 // ignore pathvariables from parent
 @GetMapping("/d/{d}")
 public String d(@PathVariable String d){
  return d;
 }

}
```

Just take over the `@Pathvaribles` of the Parent-class

Then a request like http://localhost:8080/a/x/b/y/c/z
will return "xyz"

And a request like http://localhost:8080/a/ignore-a/b/ignore-b/d/capure-d
will return "capure-d"